# Toggle effect in a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to convert and *old component* that has been coded in *vanillaJS into react* to add it into a new project.

The component consists in two `inputs`, one with the type `range` and the other one with the type `checkbox` and two `variables` that change with the hook `useState`  that change his state depending the events that are trigged with the `input's`.
For example when someone move the `input` with the type `range` the funcion `handlePriceChange` it's fired and the two `variables` are `setted` with the new values based in the `range`, at the same time the function check if the `input` with the type `checkbox` is `checked`, if this is `true` a 25% will be subtracted from the `price` variable, otherwise it will return the same price without discount.

The problem is that eveytime I click over the `checkbox` the discount is maded but the value of the `price` return to his original state and the `range` bar return to the middle.

I was thinking a lot how to solve this, one of the best approach I think could be `useEffect`, but I'm new in react and I'm open to new ideas.

here you can see a sandbox with the code running : [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-glade-uj0ec?file=/src/App.js:69-1538)

This is the code of the component :

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(8);
  const [plan, setPlan] = useState("10k");
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const handleDiscount = () => {
    setToggle((toggle) => !toggle);
  };

  const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
    const valueChange = e.target.value;
    setValue(valueChange);
    let pricing = 8;
    if ((value > 0) & (value <= 20)) {
      setPlan("10k");
      pricing = 8;
    } else if (value > 20 && value <= 40) {
      setPlan("50k");
      pricing = 12;
    } else if (value > 40 && value <= 60) {
      setPlan("100k");
      pricing = 16;
    } else if (value > 60 && value <= 80) {
      setPlan("500k");
      pricing = 24;
    } else if (value > 80 && value <= 100) {
      setPlan("1M");
      pricing = 36;
    }

    if (toggle === true) {
      setPrice(pricing - pricing * 0.25);
    } else {
      setPrice(pricing);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="range"
        name="range"
        value={value}
        min="0"
        max="100"
        className="slider"
        id="range"
        onChange={handlePriceChange}
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="discount"
        className="discount"
        id="discount"
        onClick={handleDiscount}
        onChange={handlePriceChange}
      />
      <> {price} </>
      <hr />
      <> {plan} Pageviews </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the code of the original version in vanillaJS :

```js
const range = document.getElementById('range');
const pageviewsCount = document.getElementById('pageviews-count');
const toggleDiscount = document.getElementById('toggle_discount');
const price = document.getElementById('price');

function handlePricingChanges(value) {
    let pricing = 8;

    if ((value > 0) & (value <= 20)) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '10K Pageviews';
        pricing = 8;
    } else if (value > 20 && value <= 40) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '50K Pageviews';
        pricing = 12;
    } else if (value > 40 && value <= 60) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '100K Pageviews';
        pricing = 16;
    } else if (value > 60 && value <= 80) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '500K Pageviews';
        pricing = 24;
    } else if (value > 80 && value <= 100) {
        pageviewsCount.textContent = '1M Pageviews';
        pricing = 36;
    }

    if (toggleDiscount.checked) {
        const totalValue = pricing - pricing * 0.25;
        price.textContent = `$${totalValue}.00`;
    } else {
        price.textContent = `$${pricing}.00`;
    }


}

range.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    console.log('range value :>> ', event.target.value);
    const value = range.value;
    handlePricingChanges(value);
});

toggleDiscount.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    console.log('range value :>> ', event.target.value);
    const value = range.value;
    handlePricingChanges(value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the `price` state intact, without `discount` applied since it's a derived value from `price` and `hasDiscount` (I would change `toggle` state to that naming or something similar).

Remove `onChange` from checkbox input, keep only `onClick`. To show Price you would calculate based on `hasDiscount` state:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(8);
  const [plan, setPlan] = useState("10k");
  const [hasDiscount, setHasDiscount] = useState(false);

  const handleDiscount = () => {
    setHasDiscount((hasDiscount) => !hasDiscount);
  };

  const finalPrice = hasDiscount ? price * 0.75 : price;

  const handlePriceChange = (e) => {
    const valueChange = e.target.value;
    setValue(valueChange);
    let pricing = 8;
    if ((value > 0) & (value <= 20)) {
      setPlan("10k");
      pricing = 8;
    } else if (value > 20 && value <= 40) {
      setPlan("50k");
      pricing = 12;
    } else if (value > 40 && value <= 60) {
      setPlan("100k");
      pricing = 16;
    } else if (value > 60 && value <= 80) {
      setPlan("500k");
      pricing = 24;
    } else if (value > 80 && value <= 100) {
      setPlan("1M");
      pricing = 36;
    }

    setPrice(pricing);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="range"
        name="range"
        value={value}
        min="0"
        max="100"
        className="slider"
        id="range"
        onChange={handlePriceChange}
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="discount"
        className="discount"
        id="discount"
        onClick={handleDiscount}
      />
      <> {finalPrice} </>
      <hr />
      <> {plan} Pageviews </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: slider-price]